# Edit page not rendered properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to RoR. I'm trying to learn.
This is my user_controller update/edit part.

```
def edit
    binding.break
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #binding.break
    
    if @user.update(params.require(:user).keep_if{|key|  @user.attributes[key] != params[:user][key]}.permit(:username, :email, :password))
         # Call to debugger
         flash[:notice] = "Article was updated successfully."
        redirect_to @user
    else
        #binding.break
        flash[:notice] = "Article was not updated successfully."
        render 'edit'
    end
    
end
```

This is my edit.html.erb file

```
<h1>Edit an existing User</h1>

<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <h2>The following errors prevented the user from being saved</h2>
  <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= puts msg%>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
 
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |f| %>
  <p> 
    <%= f.label :username %><br/> 
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br/> 
    <%= f.text_field :email %> 
  </p>
  <p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :password %><br/> 
    <%= f.password_field :password %> 
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %> 
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The success case is working fine.

For the negative case where the update fails, I wanted to print the error messages for which the update failed and render it. But currently it just renders the edit page again. Also the @user in the else part of the controller is having the values which is invalid and those are getting filled in the edit page upon rendering. I want to reset to original values and show the errors for which it got failed.

The errors can be anything like, email format not correct or something.

Server logs says

```
    ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `update'
  TRANSACTION (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `update'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
Username has already been taken
  Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 23.0ms | Allocations: 2337)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 59.2ms | Allocations: 4962)
Completed 200 OK in 152ms (Views: 87.9ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms | Allocations: 11120)
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: What you describe is the default behavior of a Rails app. In case of an error, it shows the form again with the invalid value and an error message telling what is wrong with the value. Which allows the user to correct the value and try again. So instead you want the user to redirect to the show page and tell them that there was an error but to fix it the user must go to edit manually and refill the whole form?

Comment: No. It can display the same edit page itself. But actually it's not showing the error messages. I can see the error messages in server logs via <%= puts msg%> which I'm printing. But that part is not rendered in browser. That is my issue

Comment: Try removing adding a space between `msg` and `%>` or just remove the entire `<%= puts msg%>` if that doesn't work. - it's not in a working form I have. If that works I can provide it as an answer or suggest something else.

Comment: :D No. That didnt work.

Comment: adding a space before the % here should work, you have `<%= puts msg%>`
if not, you have to check  if `@user.errors.full_messages` is printing anything, try in the console after the update fails, do `rails c` and try the reproduce the same thing, update using an existing name to provide the same error, then you check if @user.errors.full_messages has an error, and it should!
then if it is not printing the error in the view you have something wrong with the form code, if you provide a GitHub repo I can try to help further

Comment: You can scrap whatever you're trying to do with `params.require(:user).keep_if{|key|  @user.attributes[key] != params[:user][key]}.permit(:username, :email, :password)`. First off its not a good idea since you're comparing params to typecast attributes so it will fail to update the password unless you're irresponsible enough to store it as plaintext, secondly its not needed either since dirty tracking takes care of it. Just whitelist the attributes the user should be able to assign - preferably in a private method.

Comment: As to why the error messages are not rendering in the browser - my guess is that you have an error in your HTML which is messing up the rendering. Look at the rendered source and use a HTML validator.

Comment: @WagnerMoreira not using spacing around erb tags is bad for readability but doesn't actually matter to the parser. Try `require 'erb'; ERB.new('foo <%="bar"%>').result` if you want an example of this.

Comment: @max : Why I did keep_if was that, my username and email are like mandatory parameters and should be unique. So when I was updating, it was complaining for username already present, because the validation was run for the same username again. So that is why I was passing the parameters which has changed alone.

Comment: That sounds like your just covering over a bug that was trying to create new record. You definitely don't need it.

Answer (score -1):

`render 'edit'` with render edit without controller, you need to call `@user = User.find(params[:id])` before render to get original value.
If you want to show errors message, grant it to other const and render it in views

```
def edit
    binding.break
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #binding.break
    
    if @user.update(params.require(:user).keep_if{|key|  @user.attributes[key] != params[:user][key]}.permit(:username, :email, :password))
         # Call to debugger
         flash[:notice] = "Article was updated successfully."
        redirect_to @user
    else
        #binding.break
        @errors = @user.errors
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = "Article was not updated successfully."
        render 'edit'
    end    
end
```

in view, using `@errors.full_messages`